# How to Access Text in a Text Field

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm going through the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1) to try to understand how to use the UI builder.  The issue I'm having is that whenever I drag a "text field" from the list of UI elements onto my canvas and connect that new text element to my code, the text editor is of class `NSTextField`, which doesn't have a `text` attribute.  The tutorials, however, all say that this UI element should be a `UITextField`, which should have a `text` field.  Is there something I'm missing?  The documentation isn't entirely new, maybe it is out of date?

Comment: UITextField is for iOS. NSTextField is for macOS.

Comment: Wow, instant answer.  You are correct.  I'm not interested in building iOS apps, just desktop apps, and I made the terrible assumption of thinking that the documentation would be ok, as I didn't see documentation on using Xcode for native apps.